# Edit Page 'Custom Page' get content from other table

Tags: magento-1.8, cms, page-content

How can I get content in cms edit page from other table?

Which function should be overwritten?

I want to change the table where the content in wysiwyg editor is getting from another table.

How can i change this?

I mean on changing the SQl table, by default magento is reading content from (cms_page) but now I want to get from other table. Any help please

Answer (score 2):

Ok, depending on what you want to do there are a few ways.

The most simple one is to overwrite via your module xml the "/config/global/models/cms_resource/entities/page/table" entry. You need some knowledge about the xml structure of magento for this.

Another way is to write a rewrite for the Mage_Cms_Model_Resource_Page class, please read for this, how to properly rewrite a class, and keep in mind, you dont have to extend from this class, you can also extend from a parent class, you only should implement all public methods of it.